# With pyodbc on SQL Server, create table using select * into table from openrowset(BULK ... ) has no effect

Tags: sql-server-2008, python-2.7, sql-server-2012, pyodbc, openrowset

Environment: Windows 64bit, python 2.7.8 (32 bit), pyodbc v. 3.0.7

For what I need to do, I cannot use linkedservers, per internal policy.

Using python, I'm attempting to:

1. Export a table's data (*.dat) and its structure (format - *.fmt)
   from    one Sql Server (either 2008 or 2012) using bcp. The exported
   files    sit on my local machine. I make 2 BCP calls: one to get the
   format    (.fmt) file, another to get the data (.dat) (could not
   find a way to    do both in one step)
2. Import data of the given table into a database - MyDatabase - where I have full permission (per DBA's claim), and  on either the same SQL server but different database, or on another server altogether. Here, my primary goal is to automate both the creation of the table to be imported (based on the exported fmt file), and the actual importing of its data.

I've got point 1 working, where I can dynamically specify the server, catalog, schema, and table to export, and python automagically creates the table.dat and table.fmt files on my local machine under a dedicated folder - DedicatedShareFolder

DedicatedShareFolder is a shared folder on my local machine that stores the exported tables and their fmt files. It is accessible to the SQL Servers I'm trying to import those tables into.

In point 2, I used python to build a SQL statement as follows:

```
sql = "select * into %s from
openrowset(BULK '\\\\%s\\sqltemp\\%s.dat', 
FORMATFILE = '\\\\%s\\sqltemp\%s.fmt') as A" %(newTableName,os.environ['COMPUTERNAME'],
table,os.environ['COMPUTERNAME'],table)
```

Which ends up looking like:

```
select A.* into MyDatabase.dbo.blah48 from
openrowset(BULK '\\MyMachineName\DedicatedShareFolder\table.dat', 
FORMATFILE = '\\MyMachineName\DedicatedShareFolder\table.fmt') as A;
```

I create a connection to the SQL server that has MyDatabase, and execute:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s' % (server, catalog, login, pw))
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
rows = cursor.execute(sql).rowcount
print "Done importing %s rows" %rows
```

I get:

```
Done importing 606597 rows
```

Alas, the table was not created

I ran a trace on my local machine using 'ODBC Data Source Administration''s 'Tracing' tab. I opened the log file, and could not find any error pertaining to the creation of the table. I do see entries like this:

```
test_DB 5200-5a28   EXIT  SQLDriverConnectW  with return code 1 (SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        HDBC                0x03C59190
        HWND                0x00000000
        WCHAR *             0x74C28B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x74C28B34 <Invalid buffer length!> [-3]
        SWORD                       -3 
        SWORD *             0x00000000
        UWORD                        0 <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>

        DIAG [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'mydatabase'. (5701) 

        DIAG [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english. (5703) 

        DIAG [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)
```

I suspect 'Invalid buffer length' has no effect here (couldn't find info on it in my search), and I do see driver changing context and language successfully.

I also see few entries in trace log like this:

```
test_DB 50c0-4fec   EXIT  SQLGetTypeInfo  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        HSTMT               0x03AC8E80
        SWORD                       12 <SQL_VARCHAR>

        DIAG [24000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state (0)
```

Nothing significant turned out in my search that would indicate 'invalid cursor state' has any effect here. Above entry could be due to other parts of code I'm still working on.

further down the trace log, I see:

```
test_DB 50c0-4fec   ENTER SQLExecDirect 
        HSTMT               0x03ACB5B0
        UCHAR *             0x025BBB94 [      -3] "select A.* into MyDatabase.dbo.blah48 from
openrowset(BULK '\\MyMachineName\DedicatedShareFolder\table.dat', 
FORMATFILE = '\\MyMachineName\DedicatedShareFolder\table.fmt') as A\ 0"
        SDWORD                    -3

test_DB 50c0-4fec   EXIT  SQLExecDirect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x03ACB5B0
        UCHAR *             0x025BBB94 [      -3] "select A.* into MyDatabase.dbo.blah48 from
openrowset(BULK '\\MyMachineName\DedicatedShareFolder\table.dat', 
FORMATFILE = '\\MyMachineName\DedicatedShareFolder\table.fmt') as A\ 0"
        SDWORD                    -3

test_DB 50c0-4fec   ENTER SQLRowCount 
        HSTMT               0x03ACB5B0
        SQLLEN *            0x0027EFD4

test_DB 50c0-4fec   EXIT  SQLRowCount  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x03ACB5B0
        SQLLEN *            0x0027EFD4 (606597)
```

trace file indicates table was created. Alas it wasn't.

Out of desperation, I looked under every database on the server I'm testing on. No blah tables anywhere, even though MyDatabase is the only one I have with write permission

If I execute the same "select * into ... openrowset ... bulk ... " statement in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, it succeeds (logged in as the same user used in python script)

I use functions in the same script to perform many other SQL-related tasks, successfully. The import is the only thing not working.

I've also run every negative unit test I could think of to make sure no variable is getting changed midway. Nothing.

I'm a beginner in python. I'm either doing something gravely wrong in my code, or ?

if "select * into .. openrowset etc" type of statement cannot be used to achieve my goal, what other SLQ solution can I use to create a table and load its data, based on its BCP dat and fmt files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic commit of transactions is disabled in the [Connection](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Connection) object by default. All of your requested work is actually being done, the transaction is just being rolled back when the connection is closed.

Couple options:

1. Commit your changes with either the [Connection.commit()](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#commit) or [Cursor.commit()](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#commit). They are functionally the same, `Cursor.commit()` was added so it's not *necessary* to keep up with the `Connection` object.
2. Set the `autocommit` variable to `True` when the connection is created. Note that it is an argument for the [pyodbc.connect()](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Module#connect) function, **it's not part of the connection string**. Setting `autocommit` with your coding style would be:

   ```
   ....
   cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s' % (server, catalog, login, pw),
                         autocommit=True)
   ....
   ```